Changing line breaks in WolframScript
Is there any command parameter for WolframScript that changes after how many characteres a continuation line is inserted? For example, using // MatrixForm output with continuation breaks is rather pointless. Or is the value fixed due to Win/Dos limitations?

The option is called PageWidth, and you need to set it to the standard output stream.
Options["stdout"]
(* { ..., PageWidth -> 78, ...} *)

SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> Infinity];



THX! Of course I'm still limited by monitor size. (And eye resolution - I bet font size can also be adapted somewhere...)

On Windows, you can use CTRL+Mouse Scroll to change the zoom. Or right click on the title bar, then Settings ...
